# Facebook iOS SDK 3.17 crashed on iOS 5.x

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ios5

In my iOS project, I am using facebook sdk 3.17.

My project information,

XCODE 6.1.1
Minimum iOS version 5.0 (thats why I am using 3.17 version)

The only code about facebook is
In AppDelegate

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:FACEBOOK_ID];
[FBAppEvents activateApp];
```

It works on iOS6 and later but application is crashing on iOS 5.1 while opening.

Thanks for your answers

This is the information message on Facebook Developer Page
[image]

Comment: Facebook is notorious for requiring you to constantly upgrade to the latest version of its SDK, the old SDKs are useless and the reason for this is because the Facebook data schema is constantly changing as well. I have apps that are working perfectly then suddenly stops working just because fb has an upgrade.

Comment: But there is a message on facebook developer page for this, so I am waiting it to work on iOS 5.x. I added the message above

Comment: It means it is not going to work on on IOS 5.x anymore - FB is just like that.  doesn't care about developers like you. Sorry